# Use jQuery to animate navigation bar on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, jquery-animate

Can I use jQuery to animate my navigation bar so that it changes color over scroll? What I want is a navigation bar with a rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3) background-color when scrolled to top, and rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) when scrolled 600px down from the top.

I know it is possible to make this with something like:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
         $('.navbar-container-fixed').addClass('white');
     }
     else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 600) {
        $('.navbar-container-fixed').removeClass('white');
     }
});
```

but that will change the color without an animation. What I want is a progressive color change, so that the background color slowly changes to white as you go down the page. So that it goes like this:

```
0 px from top: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3)

100px from top: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.4167)

200px from top: rgba(119, 119, 119, 5.334)
```

and so on.

Comment: why not set the background to a gradient? Or, alternatively, use `.animate()`

Comment: Why should I set the background to a gradient? I thought I could use .animate(), but how do I make it a smooth progressive color change, and not just a momentarily change.

Comment: search 'jquery animate' - there's an option there for setting animation timing.

Comment: I know. But the timing is should not depend on time, but on how far the page is scrolled down. Is the question understandable?

Comment: sort of. [I saw this if it helps?](http://codepen.io/nckprsn/pen/IGpmc)

Comment: Not really, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about checking the max available scrolling height, and setting the color according to the scrolled position?

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var col_var = Math.round((255/$("body")[0].scrollHeight)*$(window).scrollTop());
    $(".navbar-container-fixed").css({
        "background-color":"rgb("+col_var+","+col_var+","+col_var+")"
    });

});
```

```css
.navbar-container-fixed{
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:2000px;
    background:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-container-fixed"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I modified it to match my needs, and it works like a dream :)